# Debug iOS Application using distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Xcode setup with distribution certificate, when i run the application, It gets installed in the device but halts the connection in Xcode and throws an error.

The issue is, the application crashes for some reason after running in device, to get to know reason behind the crash we need access to log, and since  Xcode stops the connection post installation, we cannot collect the log.

My question is, Is it normal that the Xcode disconnect upon install if we are using distribution profile? Or is it something else that is causing this issue.

PS: Our development and testing team works remotely, the development team develops the copy with development profile which is working very good, and the testing team test it using distribution profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely normal. Distribution certificates are not meant for development, and XCode won't let you debug that application, that's why it gets disconnected from the app.

To see the logs in the device, if the application is still being executed, you can use one log viewer, like http://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/